# Autolayout ignores UITabBar (content under the bar) on iOS7

Tags: ios7, uitabbar

I've set UITabBar as Opaque in Storyboard, but i still seems to be transulcent. When I set my custom UITabBarController with `setBarStyle` there is only OpaqueBlack availible.

But that the least of the problem. No matter what I do, content of my view gets positioned under the tab bar, like it ignored by ayutolayout. On Storyboard everything looks fine. something messes up in the runtime?

Oh the most important thing. The problem occurs on iOS7 only!

Here are my ViewController settings in storyboard:

[image]

And here is problematic content (UITableView) which gets positioned under the UITabBar on ios7 app. Looks fine in storyboard though:

[image]

And finally UITableView constraints:

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Putting this on `viewDidLoad`, solves the problem:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
    [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
}
```

Comment: yes its working fine for me. but my app have Tabbacontroller alos. Rest of the viewcontroller is working fine. Issue in Tabbar view controller. suppose i have 5 tab. 1. when i click on tab (List screen open) it working fine when i click on list detail open fine. up to yet its working fine 2. when i click on tab 2 (another list) open. that time when i clickon tab1 than detail screen main view frame decrease to 64px. i have tried to forcefully increase but not working .. what can i do in this case ??

Comment: Instead of checking for a specific version, it's better to check for the existence of the selector: `if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)])`

Answer (score 9):

xCode also provides the programatic capability:

```
[self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
```

within your storyboard for a given ViewController via the **Extend Edges** section:

[image]

Simply disable both the **Under Top Bars** and **Under bottom Bars** options.   They are on by default.

Answer (score 4):

create these `macros` in your project's `<projectname>-Prefix.pch` file so they will work globally:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)              ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)
```

Then put this after `[super viewDidLoad]` in `viewDidLoad` method of every `viewController` that's having this issue:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) 
{
        [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
}
```

Comment: Instead of checking for a specific version, it's better to check for the existence of the selector: `if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)])`

Answer (score 0):

In Swift `UIRectEdgeNone` is not available. You can achieve the same with the following code:

```
edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```